# Low fee Electrum wallet transaction disappeared, now when I increase the fee it seems to be rejected as a double spend

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, electrum, doublespend, replace-by-fee

Can anyone tell me what is happening with my transactions ...

First I move some small amount and didn't see that fee was set up to low so it was "low fee" after that I've made another one and It get status "parent ....". I've read about fees and all that stuff so only thing I could do is wait, after 24h those two transactions disappeared and my balance went back to what it was before those two transactions.

I thought that they where cancelled so I made another one with higher fee. After that when I've check it at blockchain it had "double spender" tag and in electrum was "unconfirmed". After another 24h once again that transaction disappeared and my balance went back. Today I've tried to move my btc to another wallet .. made transaction with high fee and is still unconfirmed and I'm unable to see it in blockchain. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? My previous 15 transactions went without any problems ...

Comment: I have almost exactly the same issue, did you figured out with it?

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue and found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/69ii1r/at_lost_ends_with_my_unconfirmed_transaction_over/) reddit post quite helpful. I'm not a bitcoin expert but I will write an answer describing what I think is happening, since there are no other answers yet.

When you sent the first low-fee tx, it got propagated fine to the network but remained unconfirmed. When you opened the Electrum wallet a few hours later, this unconfirmed tx disappeared because your electrum wallet connected to a node which removed your tx from the mempool for being below its minimum relay fee.

So you created a second transaction, but while most nodes (including block explorers, miners) saw your transaction, they immediately ejected it out of the mempool for being an attempted double spend.

Only your first tx has any chance of going through. But if it has very low fees it might not be mined and be removed from all mempools after some time (3+ days?). So, you have to wait for the first transaction to be removed from all mempools and then create a new transaction with higher fees.

Any confirmation or correction for the above from an expert would be appreciated..

Here is what electrum [documentation](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/faq.html#my-transaction-has-been-unconfirmed-for-a-long-time-what-can-i-do) proposes for cases of unconfirmed transactions:
If you have made a transaction that is unconfirmed, you can:

- Wait for a long time. Eventually, your transaction will either be
  confirmed or cancelled. This might take several days.
- Increase the    transaction fee. This is only possible for
  ‘replaceable’    transactions. To create this type of transaction,
  you must have    enabled ‘Replace by Fee’ in your preferences, before
  sending the    transaction.
- Create a ‘Child Pays For Parent’ transaction. A CPFP is    a new
  transaction, that pays a high fee in order to compensate for    the
  small fee of its parent transaction. It can be done by the
  recipient of the funds, or by the sender, if the transaction has a
  change output. (Here is a step by step guide for this option: [link](https://data-dive.com/unconfirmed-bitcoin-transactions-electrum))